# C++ Opencv: Mat.zeros get wrong shape

Tags: c++, opencv

I defined and initialized a `Mat` variable using the `Mat::zeros`, when I print its shape, i.e. `rows`, `cols`, `channels`, it seems I get wrong values.

My code is shown as follows:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n_Channel = 3;
    int mySizes[3] = {100, 200, n_Channel};
    Mat M = Mat::zeros(n_Channel, mySizes, CV_64F);
    cout << M.rows << "," << M.cols << "," << M.channels() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The printed message is :

```
-1,-1,1
```

What's wrong with this?

I also find that if I declare a `Mat` using the following code:

```
int n_Channel = 3;
Mat M(Size(100, 200), CV_32FC(n_Channel));
cout << M.rows << "," << M.cols << "," << M.channels() << endl;
```

the outcome is correct:

```
200,100,3
```

I'm confused about this. Thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a very special [overloaded version](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a961cf7d4f82253d93bb5b8ff54522087) of the `cv::Mat::zeros` method.

Let's have a look at the following code:

```cpp
    // Number of channels.
    const int n_Channel = 3;

    // Number of dimensions; must be 1 or 2?
    const int n_Dimensions = 2;

    // Create empty Mat using zeros, and output dimensions.
    int mySizes[n_Dimensions] = { 200, 100 };
    cv::Mat M1 = cv::Mat::zeros(n_Dimensions, mySizes, CV_64FC(n_Channel));
    std::cout << "M1: " << M1.rows << "," << M1.cols << "," << M1.channels() << std::endl;

    // Create empty Mat using constructor, and output dimensions.
    cv::Mat M2 = cv::Mat(cv::Size(100, 200), CV_64FC(n_Channel), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    std::cout << "M2: " << M2.rows << "," << M2.cols << "," << M2.channels() << std::endl;
```

which gives the following output:

```
M1: 200,100,3
M2: 200,100,3
```

So, basically you have to move the "channel number info" from `mySizes` to the `cv::Mat::zeros` method. Also, you have to pay attention to the order of the image dimensions provided in `mySizes`, since it seem to differ from the constructor using `cv::Size`. I guess the latter one is `width x height`, whereas the first one is `number of rows x number of cols`.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, cv::Mat::zeros(2, mySizes, CV_64FC(n_Channel)), what does the first argument stands for, i.e. the 2? I find in the document that it is the "Array dimensionality". But I don't quite understand what it is, because the Mat I defined has three dimensions, namely the rows, cols, channels...

Comment: @pfc I edited my answer to bypass the hard-coded 2. Apparently, `n_Dimensions` will only give reasonable results for values 1 and 2. My guess is, that all these `Mat` methods are specifically designed for 1-dimensional and 2-dimensional matrices, whereas the number of channels is handled separately. Maybe someone else can provide more information on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

How to init CV mat :

```
cv::Mat test = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(100, 200), CV_64F);
```

As you can see, the first parameter is the Size cf :

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html